PyAutoGUI was unable to import pyscreeze
Недавно начал писать программу-сканер для своего проекта. Она смотрит, есть ли на выбранной области экрана определенный объект (картинка), и при наличии его нажимается определенная клавиша. В общем, ниже код:
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import time

# Функция для нахождения картинки на экране
def find_image(target_img, screen_img):
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(screen_img, target_img, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    return np.where(result >= 0.8)  # Порог для совпадения

# Параметры области захвата экрана
capture_area = (320, 830, 900, 900)  # (x, y, width, height)

# Загрузка изображения для поиска
target_image = cv2.imread('red.png')  # Изображение, которое ищем
key_to_press = 'left'  # Клавиша, которую нужно нажать

while True:
    # Захват экрана
    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot(region=capture_area)
    screen_image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screenshot), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    # Поиск изображения на экране
    locations = find_image(target_image, screen_image)

    if len(locations[0]) > 0:
        print("Изображение найдено!")
        pyautogui.press(key_to_press)  # Нажимаем клавишу
        time.sleep(1)  # Задержка, чтобы не нажимать слишком быстро

    time.sleep(0.1)  # Задержка перед следующим сканированием

Настроил область захвата, выбрал картинку. (Вот директория с программой, в ней картинки: https://imgur.com/wLOdnFt)
При запуске появляется такая ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\Desktop\scaner\scaner.py", line 20, in <module>
    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot(region=capture_area)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\Desktop\scaner\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 228, in _couldNotImportPyScreeze
    raise PyAutoGUIException(
pyautogui.PyAutoGUIException: PyAutoGUI was unable to import pyscreeze. (This is likely because you're running a version of Python that Pillow (which pyscreeze depends on) doesn't support currently.) Please install this module to enable the function you tried to call.

Process finished with exit code 1


Прочитал, что то с версией pillow и python. У меня версия python 3.12, версия pillow 10.4.0
Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает, что делать, в чем ошибка?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73925578/pyautogui-was-unable-to-import-pyscreeze

Ну доставьте пакет pyscreeze, это же первое, что должно в голову приходить.

@CrazyElf дак это понятно, я это и делал)

Попробуйте переустановить библиотеки, используемые в программе.
Откройте командную строку и напишите следующие команды:
pip uninstall pyautogui
pip uninstall pyscreeze
pip install pyautogui

Это должно помочь.

Переустановка помогла решить проблему, описанную в вопросе?

Перелогиниться забыли?) Если что, самоответ вполне разрешен. Если это действительно решило вашу проблему - так и пишите, такие-то команды решили мою проблему, а не так, как будто вы другому человеку пишите.

@insolor, а я же самоответ и сделал, или нет?

Да. Но если вы пишете себе, не нужно писать, как будто это не вы не себе пишете. Если вы уже попробовали, и вам помогло это решение, не пишите себе "попробуйте" и "это должно помочь". Так и пишите: "мне помогло"

@insolor, это у человека такой стиль написания, не придирайтесь)) Вот когда он примет ответ, тогда уже ни у кого не останется сомнений)

@Chaos_Sower, это очень странный стиль, за 10+ лет впервые вижу такое.

@insolor, вот, например)) (я этим стилем не горжусь теперь  — потом надо будет всё по-нормальному написать)) )

@Chaos_Sower ну, допустим когда это уверенное утверждение "замените" - то это в целом еще ок. Но когда человек пишет "попробуйте" - это звучит так, как будто сам человек этого не пробовал, и не уверен, что это сработает. И типа пишет себе: "я не знаю, работает это или нет, но попробуйте вот это"

@insolor, ахах, да, может и показаться, что так)) Это зависит от интонации))

@Родион так вам помогло или нет в итоге? Вы пробовали?

в новых версиях (наверное с 11 работает чутка хуже)
import pyautogui 
import os 
import pyscreeze 
import cv2

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
bur = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('s17_t.jpg', confidence=0.9)

крч обязательно нужно подключать cv2 и параметр confidence=0.9
